# Multiple Domains/IPs for single website via IIS

Tags: iis, web-hosting, china

Here is my situation.

A factory of ours in China can no longer access our site that we use to record and prepare orders for production and shipping. We suspect that it has been blocked for whatever reason and that getting it unblocked will be nigh to impossible.

So what I've been tasked to do is to create an alternate route for them to access this site so they can pull the data they need, while making no/minimal changes to how the rest of the world will access the site.

I'll admit I'm no expert, but what I'd like to do is bind a new domain to our site alongside the old one, each with its own dedicated IP. (IE site1.com/x.x.x.101 and site2.com/x.x.x.102). The idea being that I can change the Dedicated IP address of site2.com as needed and leave site1 as is. Is this possible and how?

Basically, I need both sites to access the same data from the same host. So that any changes from either domain will be reflected on the other, and vice versa.

The site is hosted locally, on winsrv2016 via IIS

***And before anyone says it, No VPN/proxy is not an option. The factory owners are unwilling as the laws are really vague on the use of VPNs to bypass blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just create a new DNS record in your public DNS zone for the new website using a different ip address than the existing website. Then make sure your network firewall is configured correctly to forward traffic for the new ip address to the web server.

You shouldn't need to do anything in IIS if the old website and the new website are the same website in IIS. Traffic for either of the DNS names will be sent to your firewall, which will forward them to the web server, which will capture the sessions in the default website.